# Chmod in C assigning wrong permissions

Tags: c, linux, file, file-permissions, chmod

The following is my code for a method that copies a file from a path to a file to a directory provided as the destination. The copy works perfectly fine, however my chmod call assigns the wrong permissions to the copied file in the destination. If the permission in the source is 644, the copied file has a permission of 170 or 120.

I have been attempting to debug this for hours and it's driving me slightly crazy so any help is greatly appreciated.

```
void copy_file(char* src, char* dest) {

    char a;
    //extract file name through a duplicate ptr
    char* fname = strdup(src);
    char* dname = basename(fname);
    //open read and write streams
    FILE* read;
    FILE* write;

    read = fopen(src, "r");
    chdir(dest);
    write = fopen(dname, "w");

    //error checking
    if (read == NULL) //|| (write == NULL))
    {   
        perror("Read Error: ");
        exit(0);
    }

    else if (write == NULL)
    {
        perror("Write Error: ");
        exit(0);
    }

    //write from src to dest char by char
    while (1){
        a = fgetc(read);
        if (a == EOF) 
        {
            break;
        }
        fputc(a, write);
    }

    //close files
    fclose(read);
    fclose(write);

    // this is where I attempt to assign source file permissions
    //and it goes horribly wrong    
    struct stat src_st;
    if(stat(src, &src_st)){
        perror("stat: ");
    }

    chmod(dname, src_st.st_mode);
    printf("%o\n", src_st.st_mode & 0777);
}
```

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: `char a; ... a = fgetc(read);` is wrong. `fgetc` returns `int` for a reason.

Comment: `fname = strdup(src);` is a memory leak. You never free `fname`.

Comment: If both `fopen(src, "r")` and `fopen(dname, "w")` fail, your code will display the error from `dname` but claim it's from reading `src`.

Comment: `exit(0)` indicates successful termination. Use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` for errors.

Comment: There are no error checks on `chdir` and `chmod`. Do they even succeed?

Comment: Thanks a lot, will fix those. Any help regarding the chmod call is greatly appreciated

Comment: If `stat` fails, your code outputs a message but then just keeps running (with garbage values in `src_st`).

Comment: If you give it a src file like "test.data", your code truncates the source file. Very bad. This is because basename("test.data") is "test.data". If the `chdir` fails, it will open the source for writing. Basically, check ***all*** your system calls.

Comment: Check that src_st.st_mode actually has the value you expect, and check that chmod succeeded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `fopen(src, "r")`, then you `chdir(dest)`. This means that when you later call `stat(src, &src_st)`, there is no reason to think that `stat` will access the same file as `fopen` did, or indeed that `stat` will access any file at all.

If `stat` fails, you proceed to call `chmod` anyway, so you pass whatever random junk was in `src_st.st_mode` to `chmod`.

You should use `fstat(fileno(read), &src_st)` before calling `fclose(src)`, instead of calling `stat(src, &src_st)`.

Comment: This works, thank you very much from someone still grappling with C!!

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is you have to check your system calls like `fopen`, `chdir`, and `stat` *immediately*.

For example, first thing I tried was `copy_file( "test.data", "test2.data" )` not realizing it expected a destination *directory*.

```
char* fname = strdup(src);
char* dname = basename(fname);
```

`dname` is now `test.data`, same as the source.

```
read = fopen(src, "r");     // succeeds
chdir(dest);                // fails
write = fopen(dname, "w");  // blows away test.data, the source
```

You do eventually check `read` and `write`, but after the damage has been done.

Blowing away your source file is *really bad*. It's important that your code deals with failed system calls. If you don't, it will sail along causing confusion and destruction.

---

Most system calls in C return 0 for success. This is an anti-pattern where the return value is an error flag, so false is failure, and anything else indicates what kind of error (though `stat` doesn't use that, it uses errno).

When it fails, `stat` returns -1 which is true. So this is the wrong way around.

```
struct stat src_st;
if(stat(src, &src_st)){
    perror("stat: ");
}
```

Instead, you have to check for non-zero.

```
    struct stat src_st;
    if(stat(src, &src_st) != 0 ){
        // Note that I don't use perror, it doesn't provide enough information.
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not stat %s: %s\n", src, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }
```

As you can guess this gets tedious in the extreme, and you're going to forget, or do it slightly different each time. You'll want to write wrappers around those functions to do the error handling for you.

```
FILE *fopen_checked( const char *file, const char *mode ) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(file, mode);
    if( file == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open '%s' for '%s': %s", file, mode, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    return fp;
}
```

It's not the best error handling, but it will at least ensure your code appropriately halts and catches fire.

---

A note about `chdir`: *if you can avoid it don't use it*. `chdir` affects the global state of the program, the current working directory, and globals add complexity to everything. It's very, very easy for a function to change directory and not change back, as yours does. Now your process is in a weird state.

For example, if one did `copy_file( "somefile", "foo" )` this leaves the program in `foo/`. If they then did `copy_file( "otherfile", "foo" )` they'd be trying to copy foo/otherfile to foo/foo/otherfile.

And, as [@robmayoff pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42890752/14660), your `stat` fails because the process is now in a different directory. So even the function doing the `chdir` is confused by it.

Ensuring that your functions always `chdir` back to the original directory in a language like C is very difficult and greatly complicates error handling. Instead, stay in your original directory and use functions like `basename` to join paths together.

---

Finally, avoid mixing your file operations. Use filenames or use file descriptors, but try not to use both. That means if you're using `fopen`, use `fstat` and `fchmod`. You might have to use `fileno` to get a file descriptor out of the FILE pointer.

This avoids having to carry around and keep in sync two pieces of data, the file descriptor and the filename. It also avoids issues with `chdir` or the file being renamed or even deleted, the file descriptor will still work so long as it remains open.

Answer (score 0):

This is also a problem:

```
char a;

...

while (1){
    a = fgetc(read);
    if (a == EOF) 
    {
        break;
    }
    fputc(a, write);
}
```

`fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  Per [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), **[7.21.7.1  The `fgetc` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.1)**:

> **7.21.7.1  The `fgetc` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int fgetc(FILE *stream);
> ```

Assuming `sizeof( int ) > sizeof( char )`, `char` values are signed, 2s-complement integers, and `EOF` is an `int` defined to be `-1` (all very common values), reading a file with `char a = fgetc( stream );` will fail upon reading a valid `0xFF` character value.  And if your implementation's default `char` value is `unsigned char`, `char a = fgetc( stream );` will never produce a value that matches `EOF`.